# TF: Fetch argument x has invalid type <type 'numpy.float32'>, must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a float32 into a Tensor or Operation.)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have a time series model in TF. It's basically a simple auto-regressive model.

The original `y` is a vector of length 100 (`n`).

I get the float is not tensor error (as per subject). I only get it at the second instance though.

```
LR = .01
STEPS = 100

def Net(x, w, b):
  # x has 2 previous values
  x = [x[-1], x[-2], x[-1] - x[-2]]
  x = tf.reshape(x, [1, 3])
  x = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, w[0]), b[0])
  pred = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, w[1]), b[1])
  return pred

y_data = y - np.mean(y)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [2], name='x')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1], name='y')
w = [tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3])), tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 1]))]
b = [tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1])), tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]))]
pred = Net(x, w, b)
cost = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.subtract(pred, y))))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=LR).minimize(cost)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init)
  for step in range(STEPS):
    # random samples of data
    ts = np.random.choice(np.arange(2, n), int(n * .5), replace=False)
    for t in ts:
      x_data = [y_data[t - 2], y_data[t - 1]]
      y_data_cur = [y_data[t]]
      print(x_data, y_data_cur, x, y, pred)
      _, cost, p = sess.run([optimizer, cost, pred], feed_dict={x: x_data, y: y_data_cur})
      print(cost, p)
    if step % 10 == 0:
      print(step, cost)
```

Comment: I have error on this line `y_data = y - np.mean(y)`, and this error is very understandable.

Comment: this is not the full code, generate `y` as random normal of shape [100] fist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run your model:

```
_, cost, p = sess.run([optimizer, cost, pred], feed_dict={x: x_data, y: y_data_cur})
```

You are overwriting the `cost` variable, which used to hold the TensorFlow tensor for the cost, with its evaluated value, so the next iteration fails. Just change the name of the variable:

```
_, cost_val, p = sess.run([optimizer, cost, pred], feed_dict={x: x_data, y: y_data_cur})
```

And of course replace `cost` with `cost_val` in the `print` statements.